# css - how to draw an arrow on ::after

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which draws a line between the bullets using ::after when I click a button.

What I would like is to have an arrow head on the end of the line. How can achieve this?

HTML

```
<div class="card-body">
   <div class="stepper-bar">
       <div class="step">
           <p class="step-text">Step 1</p>
           <div class="bullet">1</div>
       </div>
       <div class="step">
           <p class="step-text">Step 2</p>
           <div class="bullet">2</div>
       </div>
       <div class="step">
           <p class="step-text">Step 3</p>
           <div class="bullet">3</div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <button id="previousBtn" type="button">Previous</button>
   <button id="nextBtn" type="button">Next</button>
   <button id="finishBtn" type="button">Finish</button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
const  previousBtn  =  document.getElementById('previousBtn');
const  nextBtn  =  document.getElementById('nextBtn');
const  finishBtn  =  document.getElementById('finishBtn');
const  content  =  document.getElementById('content');
const  bullets  =  [...document.querySelectorAll('.bullet')];

const MAX_STEPS = 8;
let currentStep = 1;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click',  ()  =>  {
    bullets[currentStep  -  1].classList.add('completed');
    currentStep  +=  1;
    previousBtn.disabled  =  false;
    if  (currentStep  ===  MAX_STEPS)  {
        nextBtn.disabled  =  true;
        finishBtn.disabled  =  false;
    }
});


previousBtn.addEventListener('click',  ()  =>  {
    bullets[currentStep  -  2].classList.remove('completed');
    currentStep  -=  1;
    nextBtn.disabled  =  false;
    finishBtn.disabled  =  true;
    if  (currentStep  ===  1)  {
        previousBtn.disabled  =  true;
    }
});

finishBtn.addEventListener('click',  ()  =>  {
    location.reload();
});
```

CSS

```
.stepper-bar  {
    display:  flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.step  {
    flex: 1;
    text-align:  center;
}

.step-text  {
margin-bottom:  10px;
color:  #28a745;
}


.bullet {
    border: 1px solid #28a745;
    height: var(--circle-size);
    width: var(--circle-size);
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #28a745;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: background-color 500ms;
    line-height: var(--circle-size);
}


.bullet.completed  {
    color:  white;
    background-color:  #28a745;
}


.bullet.completed::after {
    content: '';
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    left: calc(50% + var(--circle-size));
    bottom: calc(var(--circle-size) / 2);
    height: 2px;
    width: calc(100% + var(--circle-size));
    background-color: #28a745;
}
```

The above code gives me the following (after clicking the next button):

[image]

What I would like is this:

[image]

I tried using

```
content: '\2192';
```

But I just get this:

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the most straightforward solution is either using **clip-path** or an svg to handle this scenario.

You can make the div that represents your line + arrow rectilinear and apply a clip path like so:

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  clip-path: polygon(0 45%, 90% 45%, 90% 35%, 100% 50%, 90% 65%, 90% 55%, 0 55%);
 }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

So, in your code it might look roughly like this:

```
.bullet.completed::after {
 content: '';
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 left: calc(50% + var(--circle-size));
 bottom: calc(var(--circle-size) / 2);
 height: 20px;
 width: calc(100% + var(--circle-size));
 background-color: #28a745;
 clip-path: polygon(0 45%, 90% 45%, 90% 35%, 100% 50%, 90% 65%, 90% 55%, 0 55%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it does not work for me. When I add the clip-path I just see a very short line where the line I had ends.

Comment: Did you increase the height of the div? What clip-path is doing is, essentially, clipping out a portion of the element it is affecting by plotting out positions in a grid.

Note the sequential percentages inside of the parenthesis. (0, 45%) is one plotted point, and so on. You need the element it's affecting to be large enough that you then "clip away" material to make the shape you want, it doesn't just replace what you have.

Comment: Ah, I see. You are correct, I neglected to increase the height of the div. This works now. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, you can also easily animate between two clip-paths if they have the same number of points on the polygon. You could transition your arrow from left to right, for example.

Comment: Sounds like fun. Something to play around with if I can find the time. Meanwhile your answer go me to where I wanted to be. Thanks again.