# What's the easiest way to create horizontal and vertical arrows in components in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

A horizontal line can be created simply by something like this:

```
<hr style={{ width: "80%", border: "1px solid black" }} />
```

We can adjust the width, length etc.

If I want to show an arrow pointing towards right direction instead of line, what's the best way to do that (Obviously with some customisation available like width, length, color, etc.)?

[image: arrow image]

There are a lot of libraries available, but almost all of them require giving two components and it draws from one component to another.

If instead of the line definition, I replace it arrow component, it should show an arrow like in the image. This seems like a fairly simple request, but I couldn't find any such methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css - how to draw an arrow on ::after](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73348465/328193)  Basically, either an SVG or the use of CSS `clip-path` are likely your best bet, short of using an image.

Comment: please read about [the element <marker>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker) in SVG

Answer (score 2):

You could add an `::after` element to the `<hr>` that will add the arrow:

```js
const CustomHR = () => <hr className='customHR' />;

ReactDOM.render(<CustomHR />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.customHR { 
   margin-top: 50px;
   width: 80%;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.customHR::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    display: block;
    border-right: 3px solid;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This isn't exactly an arrow. It's line and that 'v' pointer next to each other. This isn't appearing like an arrow if the user zooms the page.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with SVG:

```html
<svg width="300" height="20">
  <path d="M 0,10 H 300 L 290,0 M 300,10 L 290,20" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: let me check with this.